# How can I create a timer that delays all the code behind it?

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```js
console.log(123)
timer(2)
console.log(456)
```

What can I do to make 456 be displayed after 123?

`await` can only be used in the async function and top level bodies of modules, and sometimes said top level body is not in a module? Also, it doesn't seem possible to await a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?  Presumably you'll be going through [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), but how to proceed will depend on how you want to use callbacks, or promises, or promises wrapped in the async/await syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a delay function which would resolve after some time as use that for simulating the delay.

```js
// This resolves the promise after "time" milliseconds
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(null), time);
  })
}

async function main() {
  console.log(123);
  await delay(2000);
  console.log(456);
}

main()
```

Comment: It works, although it would be nice if it didn't have to be an async function, though that's probably not possible so thanks anyway :)

Comment: return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time)) works just as well as  return new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => resolve(null), time)})